# Double array by duplicating values in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there any libraries functions (Scipy, Numpy, ?) that can double the array size by duplicating the values ? Like this :

```
  [[1, 2, 4],        [[1. 1. 2. 2. 4. 4.]
   [5, 6, 2],   ->    [1. 1. 2. 2. 4. 4.]
   [6, 7, 9]]         [5. 5. 6. 6. 2. 2.]
                      [5. 5. 6. 6. 2. 2.]
                      [6. 6. 7. 7. 9. 9.]
                      [6. 6. 7. 7. 9. 9.]]
```

Or is there a faster way to do this operation ? When the array is very large, it becomes a problem. This is what I have so far.

```
def double_array(array):
  nbr_rows, nbr_cols = array.shape

  array_new = np.zeros((nbr_rows*2, nbr_cols*2))
  for row in range(nbr_rows):
    for col in range(nbr_cols):
      array_new[row*2,col*2] = array[row,col]
      array_new[row*2+1,col*2] = array[row,col]
      array_new[row*2,col*2+1] = array[row,col]
      array_new[row*2+1,col*2+1] = array[row,col]

  return array_new

array = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [5, 6, 2], [6, 7, 9]])
array_new = double_array(array)
print(array_new)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment before, you can try [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), for instance:

```
array = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [5, 6, 2], [6, 7, 9]])
new_arr = np.repeat(np.repeat(array,2,axis=1), [2]*len(array), axis=0)

print(new_arr.astype(np.float))
```

Output:

```
[[1. 1. 2. 2. 4. 4.]
 [1. 1. 2. 2. 4. 4.]
 [5. 5. 6. 6. 2. 2.]
 [5. 5. 6. 6. 2. 2.]
 [6. 6. 7. 7. 9. 9.]
 [6. 6. 7. 7. 9. 9.]]
```

Comment: Yes ! It speed up the computation by about 4 times on a small array !

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy.repeat`+`numpy.tile`:

```
N,M = 2,2 # rows,cols
out = np.repeat(np.tile(array, N), M).reshape(array.shape[0]*N, -1)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 6, 6, 2, 2],
       [5, 5, 6, 6, 2, 2],
       [6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9],
       [6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9]])
```

Comment: This works too ! However, the other answer is faster for my use case.

Comment: `tile` uses `repeat`

Comment: Nice to know, thanks @hpaulj I guess this explains why the two commands have a different behavior (eg. being able to create several dimensions for tile)

Answer (score 1):

Just repeat one the second and then first axes:

```
N = 2
new_arr = a.repeat(N, axis=1).repeat(N, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_arr
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 6, 6, 2, 2],
       [5, 5, 6, 6, 2, 2],
       [6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9],
       [6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9]])
```

Comment: This is actually the easiest answer to understand and might even be faster than all the others.